# MS SQL Check for duplicate in two fields

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014-express

I am trying create a trigger that will check if the Author already exist in a table based on a combination of their first and last name. From what Ive been reading this trigger should work, but when I try to insert any new author into the table it gives the "Author exists in table already!" error even though I am inserting an author that does not exist in the table.

Here is the trigger

```
USE [WebsiteDB]
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_AuthorExists] ON [dbo].[Authors]
AFTER INSERT
AS

if exists ( select * from Authors
    inner join inserted i on i.author_fname=Authors.author_fname AND i.author_lname=Authors.author_lname)
begin
    rollback
    RAISERROR ('Author exists in table already!', 16, 1);
End
```

Here is the table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Authors](
    [author_id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [author_fname] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [author_lname] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [author_middle] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Authors] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [author_id] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Any assistance would be appreciated!

Comment: You really should have a primary key on your table. The combination of these two columns should be a unique constraint instead of trying to do this with a trigger.

Comment: The author_id is the primary key, forgot to write that in. This is for a college database project and we are required to create a few triggers

Comment: @cbranch on the contrary. You do NOT want to start an explicit transaction here. A transaction will ALWAYS be started in a trigger.

Comment: you have the trigger as `AFTER INSERT`.  Doesn't this mean the new row will *already be in the table* by the time your check is run??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to do this as an INSTEAD of trigger. This also means you need to actually perform the insert inside the trigger. Something along these lines.

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[tr_AuthorExists] ON [dbo].[Authors]
instead of insert
AS
    set nocount on;

    if exists 
    ( 
        select * from Authors a
        inner join inserted i on i.author_fname = a.author_fname AND i.author_lname = a.author_lname
    )
    begin
        rollback
        RAISERROR ('Author exists in table already!', 16, 1);
    End
    else
        insert Authors
        select i.author_fname
            , i.author_lname
            , i.author_middle
        from inserted i
```